# Blackberry Webworks (Widget) JavaScript & XML/JSON Help

Tags: javascript, html, xml, json, blackberry-widgets

Here is the scenario...

Builing a Blackberry WebWorks (widget) that is used as a portal to a remote website. Most of the pages are remote. I am user customizable homepage that users can add information and links.

The way I would do this in using the JDE is to have an xml properties file that I could add/edit/remote nodes with the desired information and everytime the app would run I could process that file. However, for the webworks app to work, I need to accomplish this all via adding information to the html page.

I believe that I need to do this via javascript, however I have little javascript experience and even less blackberry API experience.

So I am looking for a beginning to end example of how to load a saved properties file either XML or JSON via JavaScript that can dynamically build the homepage of my widget. In addition, I am looking for examples of how to add/edit/remove the xml or json objects from the config file via javascript as well.

I have searched and searched, not sure if I am on the right track or not, but I have had no luck. I have seen some examples of how to edit XML in microsoft/mozilla broswers, so I am not sure if this is the same or not... If so just looking for some confirmation.

Basically here is an outline of what my head tells me needs to happen...

```
<html>
...
<script>
//Read XML/JSON Properties file
// For each item loaded process and publish html source code
</script>
...
<!-- HTML to add desired information back to properties file -->
<script>
// Perform insert/edit/delete of XML/JSON
</script>
...
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!!!
-JD

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to build, and what is your question. Could you explain yourself?

You can start looking at official Blackberry Webworks documentation and some working examples here: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/browserdev/learningresources.jsp

Best!